# dyld[26417]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib

Tags: macos, apple-m1

When I'm executing `node -v` on mac m1 Sonoma:

```
dyld[26417]: Library not loaded: /opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib
  Referenced from: <E52D9D5D-9957-386D-9594-32159BF15B1A> /opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@14/14.21.3_1/libexec/node
  Reason: tried: '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/icu4c/74.2/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libicui18n.73.dylib' (no such file, not in dyld cache)
[1]    26417 abort      node -v
```

reinstall node or reinstall icu4c not working